# aspnet customcontrol in customcontrol losts viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have two custom controls TestPanel and Header. Both are Panels.
TestPanel also contains Header.
TestPanel and Header contains only one string property Test.

I can put only Header on my form. Then it works well.
I can put TestPanel on my form and it shows TestPanel+Header. Then it doesn't work as expected, because ViewState of Header is lost (or there is another reason why Header.Test looses its value).
Here is my code:

```
public class TestPanel : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel
{
    Header myHeader;

    public string Test //Test is Header property; set/get header Test property
    {
        get
        {
            return this.MyHeader.Test;
        }
        set
        {              
            this.MyHeader.Test = value;
        }
    }

    public Header MyHeader
    {
        get
        {                
            return myHeader;
        }
        set
        {              
            myHeader = value;
        }
    }    

    public TestPanel()
    {

    }
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(Test);
        MyHeader.RenderControl(writer);
    }
}

public class Header : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel
{
    public string Test
    {
        get
        {
            string s = (string)ViewState[ID + "Test"];
            return (s == null) ? String.Empty : s;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState[ID + "Test"] = value;
        }
    }


    public Header()
    {
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(Test);
    }

}
```

On my page I use:

1) If only TestPanel on my form (this doesn't work after postback):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {          
            this.panel.Test = "paneltest";
        }

    }

protected void Unnamed2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

2) If only Header on my page (this works after postback)

```
<my:MyHeader id="header" runat="server"></my:MyHeader > 
this.header.Test = "headertest"
```

Answer (score 0):

When view state is being persisted SaveViewState() is being called recursively for each Control in the control hierarchy.  With the code provided the Header isn't being added to the Controls collection of the TestPanel and as such it isn't in the control hierarchy so the value of the Test property of the Header is lost.

For more details on how view state is saved and loaded, read [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).